# How to remove DNS records from a hosting account?

Tags: web, dns, hosting

I have purchased a domain and when I look at who.is, i get to see 4 'A' records for this domain. I have no idea how these records were added. May be before I purchased my domain, somebody else had used this domain and might have added their 'A' records in their hosting account. 
But I am not able to see these A records in my hosting account too(so that I could delete them). So how can I delete these A records which is affecting my domain?

Appreciate your help...

Answer (score 0):

You could add/delete host records in your DNS settings. You should do this in your domain name control panel. Ask your domain name register for more details.